# Finding positive integers s,t such that sa + tb = 1 in the euclidean algorithm with Python

Tags: python, algorithm

my goal is to work  backwards in the euclidean algorithm to find such positive integers s,t, and this part specifically I'm struggling with. I was already able to setup the euclidean algorithm, but working backwards i'm finding very difficult.

The idea is the following: we compute the highest common factor of any two integers, then, we work backwards, in here I'll demonstrate an example.

hcf(101, 7)

Divide 7 into 101:

```
101 - 7 * 14 = 3
```

Divide 3 into 7:

```
7 - 3 * 2 = 1
```

Divide 1 into 3

```
3 - 1 * 3 = 0
```

Now we work backwards...

```
1 = 7 - 3 * 2

1 = 7 - (101 - 7 * 14)*2

1 = 7 - 101 * 2 + 7 * 14 * 2

1 = 7 * 29 - 101 * 2
```

So specifically, those positive integers s,t are 29, 2.

Here is my code so far, the issue with the code is that for the backwards implementation I straight up am struggling with how to make it give me such a result.

The code below should give an integer s such that s = 31, which is (2 * 109 - 7 * 31). However it doesn't since its incomplete. Any advice would be appreciated.

And yes, we need those values of s, t that's the whole reason we are doing this.

```
    def div(a, b):
        q, r = divmod(a, b)
        return q, r
    
    
    list_a = []
    list_b = []
    
    c, d = 109, 7
    q, r = div(c, d)
    list_a.append((c, q, r))
    list_a.append((c, q, r))  # Needed copy..
    
    print(f"{c} - {d}*{q} = {r}")
    
    c, d = 7, 4
    q, r = div(c, d)
    list_a.append((c, q, r))
    print(f"{c} - {d}*{q} = {r}")
    
    c, d = 4, 3
    q, r = div(c, d)
    list_a.append((c, q, r))
    print(f"{c} - {d}*{q} = {r}")
    
    c, d = 3, 1
    q, r = div(c, d)
    list_a.append((c, q, r))
    print(f"{c} - {d}*{q} = {r}")
    
    del list_a[-1]
    print(list_a)
    
    x, y, z = (
        list_a[-1][0],
        list_a[-2][2],
        list_a[-1][1],
    )
    
    for k in range(1, len(list_a)):
        x, y, z = (
            list_a[-k][0],
            list_a[-k - 1][2],
            list_a[-k][1],
        )
        if x == list_a[-k][2]:
            print("hmm")
            pass
            # Assign x as list_a[-k][0] - list_a[-k][1]
        if y == list_a[-k][2]:
            print("ymm")
            pass
            # Assign y as list_a[-k][0] - list_a[-k][1]
        print("%d - %d * %d" % (x, y, z))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm discusses this, and provides pseudocode.